# Combochart with stacked bars

Tags: google-visualization

I'm currently using Google Visualisation library to (Google Charts) to visualize some of my data. I'm plotting a stacked bar graph with cumulative data, but I'd like to print an additional bar / line that shows the increase per day, rather than the total per day. I have read about [Combo Charts](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/combochart) but I can't seem to find a way to combine a stacked bar chart with a line chart.

Is this possible at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's possible, is there more you can share? specifically a sample of the data?

```js
google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
function drawChart() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Month', 'Bolivia', 'Ecuador', 'Madagascar', 'Papua New Guinea', 'Rwanda', 'Diff'],
    ['2004/05',  165,      938,         522,             998,           450,      614.6],
    ['2005/06',  135,      1120,        599,             1268,          288,      682],
    ['2006/07',  157,      1167,        587,             807,           397,      623],
    ['2007/08',  139,      1110,        615,             968,           215,      609.4],
    ['2008/09',  136,      691,         629,             1026,          366,      569.6]
  ]);

  var options = {
    title : 'Monthly Coffee Production by Country',
    vAxis: {title: 'Cups'},
    hAxis: {title: 'Month'},
    seriesType: 'bars',
    isStacked: true,
    series: {5: {type: 'line'}}
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById("barchart_values"));
  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<div id="barchart_values" style="width: 900px; height: 300px;"></div>
```

Comment: My bad, I was not aware it was possible to run "isStacked" on a ComboChart.